# Looking for a software that let only open USB drive

Tags: open-source

I'm looking for a very simple OS and can't find my way to do it. I tried with Ubuntu to achieve what I need but with no success : I get bugs every time.

All I need to so is to be able to setup an account with a password, and to let that account read the content of USB files (images, audio and video). That's all I need to be allowed, nothing more (no configuration, no Wifi, no root access, no file access to OS files, ...)

Is something like that existing ? I'm looking for this for weeks without a suitable answer :/

Thanks a lot !

Comment: No, that's not possible. What you request cannot exist: If you want to read a video from the USB stick, that will need access to a video player, e.g. VLC. This is access to OS files already. Next, VLC might require configuration to work properly. Furthermore, VLC might need to download a Codec from the Internet, so you need Wifi (perhaps).

Comment: You can use VLC in portable mode, (run it just from a USB).  Take a look at  [VLC Media Player Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/vlc_portable)

Answer (score 1):

What you could consider doing is creating a live Linux distribution on the USB stick that allows you to view the items on that stick and nothing else when you have booted from that stick.

In the past I can seen & used a couple of distributions such as this for demonstration purposes.

A good starting point would probably be [Puppy Linux](http://www.puppylinux.com/) (for it's small size) or [openSUSE](http://www.opensuse.org/) for it's packaging tools but just about any of the Linux distributions that allows packaging as a "Live" image could be so tailored.

If you remove all of the drivers for things like Ethernet, WiFi and Hard Disks from the image, making sure that the correct tools, codecs, etc., for accessing the remaining content are a part of your live image then the user, once booted into this system will only have access to the USB content.

Comment: Well the problem is that users will need to go on the computer, and they may have very basic skills.

Comment: Well the problem is that users will need to go on the computer, and they may have very basic skills.
If I can have a software that will displays an empty space only opening when a USB stick is plugged in.
Because I tried to create a user account that is super restricted, but it seems impossible to do that, they always find a way to check unauthorized files :/

Comment: This would allow you to boot the computer into a Kiosk mode where the user would only have access to the content of the USB drive.